# Servers sending XML packet via HTTPS to each other

Tags: java, xml, https, server-side

I think this might be a very stupid question.

I have 2 servers that are going to communicate with each other via HTTPS using XML packets.

My question is this, there is no webpage just a Java application. How would I get my Java app to run when it hears an XML packet from the other server? Are the messages to be sent via POST?

I know about HTTP protocols but my knowledge goes as far as webservers to sending the webpage to browsers, server to server communication w/o a webpage is baffling me. Can anyone point me to the right direction or better still to some codes that I might be able to look at.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) in your server applications so that they become clients to each other.  Then maybe simply implement REST services for the 'clients' to call.

I would suggest trying this out firstly using HTTP before trying it in HTTPS.
Of course there are other technologies you could try E.g JMS or SOAP.